# What VNC solutions are you using and why

Tags: remote-access, remote-desktop, vnc, parallels

I’m looking for a way to connect to my computer remotely using my iPad and since there are a lot of options out there I thought I would ask and see what the pros are using and what your thoughts are.

One of the main reasons I would like to connect to my computer (Mac) is because sometimes I would like to be able to try something in Xcode when I’m not setting in front of my computer. I’m mainly looking for free or cheap paid solutions.

I have been reading about Real VNC, TeamViewer and Parallel Access and they all seem like a good option but I would like to hear what other people are using.

What VNC solutions are you using and why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used team viewer to do remote support for 2 years when I was in my previous job as tech-support.
The main reason is :

It can be used to remote a station behind NAT without using port forwarding on the router (as far as I know, VNC can't do this without port forwarding)

It's feature to save target station id & credentials is also very convenient.